# Linear Ordinary Differential Equation with Nonconstant Coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What would be a good method for solving these equations?

$y''±kx^2y=0$

As I see, it could work with power series (At least with the minus), it wouldn't work with LaPlace. Is there a better methood to solve it?

Comment: Look for a power series solution...

Comment: Yup, that would be one way (I already stated it). Is there another way?

Comment: Since you're looking for "other" methods than the old faithful power series method, the one with the minus sign is Titchmarsh’s equation for parameters $\lambda=0$ and $n=1$.  However, the literature on Titchmarsh's equation is difficult to find.  Might as well go for power series :)  Or, look at mvw's answer.

Comment: I think I will really leave it with power series. I was just wondering if there was another method, perhaps one which result would be an explicit function. Now it seems there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

See the Wikipedia article on [parabolic cylinder functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function), which are special functions for solving this kind of ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't work with Laplace... curious... I must investigate:
$$ y''+kx^2y=0 $$
and, for my convenience, $y(0)=y'(0)=0$. Take the Laplace transform,
$$ s^2Y +k\frac{d^2}{ds^2}Y = 0 $$
or,
$$ Y''+\frac{1}{k}s^2Y = 0.$$
There must be some significance to this phenomenon. What does it mean to have a DEqn whose Laplace transform is once more a DEqn of the same kind in the frequency domain. Curious. Sorry, this is not an answer, but, I thought your comment could use some elaboration.

Comment: Well, my comment wasn't too deep, it was just that in the book said that LaPlace usually wouldn't work with variable coefficients.